# Three.js access objects in animation loop

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to javascript and three.js but I am trying to create a sphere out of individual points so that I can animate those later on in the animation loop.

For some reason I am not able to access the individual components of the vector the I have previously saved

```
console.log(spheres[i].position.x)
      // type error position is undefined
```

even though `spheres[i].position` is valid.

Do I need to do some sort of casting?
How is this done?

```
// global variables
let camera, scene, renderer, controls;

// +custom variables

let r = 100;
let total = 20;

let spheres = [total*total];

const map = (value, x1, y1, x2, y2) => (value - x1) * (y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1) + x2;

function init(){
   camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1 , 10000) 
  scene = new THREE.Scene()
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('bg')})
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(1,30,30);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFacc22})

  for( let i = 0; i <= total; i++){
    let lat = map(i, 0, total, -Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2);
    for( let j = 0; j <= total; j++){
      let lon = map(j, 0, total, -Math.PI, Math.PI);      
      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      mesh.position.x = r* Math.sin(lon)* Math.cos(lat) 
      mesh.position.y = r* Math.sin(lon) * Math.sin(lat)
      mesh.position.z = r* Math.cos(lon)
      spheres.push(mesh)
      scene.add(mesh)
    }
  } 
 
}

// render loop called every frame
function animate(){

  controls.update()
  
  for( let i = 0; i < spheres.length; i++){
      let vec = spheres[i].position
      
      console.log(vec)
      /*
      {
        "x": 5.823541592445462e-15,
        "y": 95.10565162951536,
        "z": -30.901699437494734
      }*/
      console.log(spheres[i].position.x)
      // type error position is undefined
      }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

// driver program 
init()
animate()
```

Comment: The problem is mostly this line: `let spheres = [total*total];` It puts a `400` as first element into the array. Then your code pushes 441 spheres behind that because your for loops use `<= total` instead of `< total`. Your render loop then tries to access the `.position` of `spheres[0]`, which isn't a sphere but the number `400`. Use `let spheres = [];` and fix the for loops and it should work fine.

Comment: I wanted to be clever and reserve sufficient space :) Thank you ! It worked